# How to fetch key value list from selection fields in Odoo 10

Tags: selection, odoo-10

I have a selection field, and I want to fetch list of all keys and values using ORM method. How can I achieve it.

```py
_name = "calling_devices"


device_type = fields.Selection([('desk','Desk'),('mobile','Mobile'),('home','Home'),('others','Others')])
```

Desired Output using ORM methods or alternate way:

`Key_Value_pair = {'desk': 'Desk', ' mobile ' : ' Mobile ', ' home ': ' Home ', ' others ': ' Others '}`

How can we achieve it?